# Problem with display rate of images (photos) using Docker + GPU

Tags: docker, gpu, nvidia

I want to ask a semi-theoretical question.
I'm using a Docker image which utilizing Nvidia-container-runtime to communicate with the GPU on my machine.
The Docker image purpose is to run an application which involves presentation of images (photos) at high rate (1 Hz - 10 Hz) (Gui application). However, as we noticed, there are some delays on the presentation rates in contrast to running the same application on bare OS (without the overhead of Docker container). Does anyone encountered this issue? Is this issue can be resolved somehow? As a note, the display rate should be as exact as possible, meaning we can't allow delays of more than 10 ms.